# Geometry-generated lines not showing on QGIS Cloud

Tags: qgis, symbology, qgis-cloud, geometry-generator

I have a points layer (tested as both a delimted text file and as a point shapefile) which is styled as shown below where the lines were created using the *Geometry Generator*. Please ignore the elongated legend :)

[image: Points]

When I upload the data onto QGIS Cloud, the generated lines disappear in both QGIS and from the online webmap even though they are clearly shown in the legend and in the symbology properties:

[image: Lines not showing]

Symbology properties:

[image: Symbology properties]

---

Is the symbology for the generated geometry not supported in QGIS Cloud? Is there a possible workaround?

*Using QGIS 2.18.17 for Win 7 64-bit.*

Comment: A workaround would be to replace the generated geometry lines with an actual line layer.

Comment: @csk - Thanks for the suggestion, that would work but I want to avoid having an extra layer :)